# Spring boot dockerized cannot reach MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker

I dockerized a MySQL database by doing:

1. `docker pull mysql`
2. `docker run --name=container_name -p 3307:3307 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql`

Now the container <container_name> is the only one I have in Docker, and its network is set by default to "bridge".

Using: `docker exec -it container_name mysql -u root -p` (then typing the password) I created a brand new database.

I tried reaching that database from my SQL client, using the specified credentials and database url:

`server: localhost or container_name, port: 3307, user: root, password: password`.

The client doesn't reach the database and I get the following errors:

> Connection refused: connect

> Communications link failure

> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

> Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

Obviously I get the same error while running my spring boot application (not dockerized yet), but the problem is something in MySQL container since the SQL client isn't working as well.

I've been reading countless questions same as mine, but the solutions that they offer, never work for me.

What's weird is the fact that in the past projects it worked fine.

I'm running Docker on Windows 10 Pro with Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to connect from **outside** of Docker, your `docker run -p` option is wrong: the second port number always needs to be the standard port number of its service.  For MySQL, that second port number needs to be 3306, always.  The two port numbers need to match.

```bash
docker run -d -p 3307:3306 ... mysql
#                     ^^^^
#                      must be the standard port number
```

If you're trying to connect from **inside** Docker, then

1. You must `docker network create` a network, and `docker run --net` all involved containers on that network
2. You must use the other container's name as a host name, not `localhost`
3. You must use the standard port number, again 3306; `docker run -p` options are ignored (and aren't required)

```bash
docker network create some-net
docker run -d --net some-net --name database \
  -p ... -e ... -v ... \
  mysql
docker run -d --net some-net --name application \
  -e MYSQL_HOST=database \
  -e MYSQL_PORT=3306 \
  my/application
```

If you're running this under Docker Compose, it automatically creates the network for you, and you can use the Compose service name as the host name.  You do not need to manually set up `networks:` or override the `container_name:`.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  database:
    image: mysql
    # ports: [...]
    # environment: [...]
    # volumes: [...]
  application:
    build: .
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: database
      MYSQL_PORT: '3306'
```

Comment: The ports are inverted and they should be: `-p 3306:3307`, but you're right, they mean nothing since I have to use it from another local container.

Comment: The [`docker run -p` syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) is `-p host-port:container-port` and the second port definitely needs to be 3306.

Comment: Unfortunately is not working that way in my case.